# Flutter web - subdomains

Tags: flutter, dart, web, subdomain

Some one can please explain me how can i use subdomain for each user in flutter web?
[Like this project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D25CxsZONvc&t=174s&ab_channel=LaravelDaily).

Thanks

Comment: @ Did you find any solution ?

Comment: any solutions yet?

Comment: Interesting question which doesn't have any answers. I mean you need to use onGenerateRoute in Flutter to build something like this "/profile/user1", "profile/user2". If I understand you correctly or it's not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just found it now...

Well, it's a bit tricky, but basically with Navigator 2 you can write whatever you want to the url and handle that back and forth with a RouterDelegate and RouteInformationParser

A full explanation can be found here:

https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade

https://medium.com/flutter-community/lets-make-the-flutter-navigator-2-bc5953251c3e

And you are going to need to fully understand this structure:
[image: Navigator diagram]

It's been a while since I last touched this but I kind of remember the key to change the URL bar is inside the RouterDelegate, overriding method setNewRoutePath. You can set the new path inside and then NotifyListeners() to do the magic.

I hope this leads you into some experimenting so you can narrow the question. I myself am still stuck in generating dynamic links from verification emails with this.